# Gender for referring to "une personne"

Tags: grammaire, genre, genre-biologique

"There is a person sleeping in the room, so I don't want to disturb him."

> Il y a une personne qui dort dans la salle, alors je ne veux pas ___ déranger.

Should I use *le* because the person is male, or *la* because *personne* is feminine?

Comment: I've never seen anyone using *dormant(e)* as an adjective in such a case (I've seen it in a figurative way when talking about a spy (*sleeper agent* = *agent dormant*) or water (*sagnant water* = *eau dormante*)). You should better use *endormi(e)* or *dormant* as a present participle.

Comment: If you're used to using "they" like in English for neutral pronouns, it's a habit you'll have to un-learn when speaking French. It's not as easy to hide the gender, for example if you say "my coworker is ..." you can have a full sentence without telling their gender in English, but not in French. You'll often have to use a default gender. Generally you'll use "*il*", but in that case it's "*elle*". If you start with "*une personne*", finish with "*la*".

Comment: By the way I'd say "*Il y a **quelqu'un qui dort**, ... **le** déranger*" here. In that case like many other times, an "-ing" verb translates with present in French. "*He's sleeping*" -> "*Il dort*" // "*I'm working*" -> "*Je travaille*". Usage of "*une personne*" vs "*quelqu'un*" is also another matter (kind of off-topic here).

Comment: @GAM PUB Je pense que répondre à la faute et expliquer pourquoi c'est une faute, est plus didactique que d'éditer la question pour corriger directement la faute. (Mais chacun fait comme il veut). La faute "dormant" est très intéressante, et peut instruire d'autres apprenants, ce n'est pas juste une coquille.

Comment: Je pense que la personne qui a produit *dormante* a reçu assez de retours ici pour comprendre cette maladresse initiale et que, par ailleurs, la question est intéressante et demande une réponse... Il me semble que nous devrions, en tant que communauté, encourager les gens à poser des questions intéressantes et à l'occasion les accompagner dans la formulation pour que leurs questions restent le centre d'intérêt de la page concernée.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sexual gender of the person you're refering to doesn't matter, that's the same as in english using "people", representing plural, but used as a singular.
So:

> Il y a une personne dormante dans la salle, alors je ne veux pas **la** déranger.

Comment: You could say *sexual gender* so it's not confused with *grammatical gender*.

Comment: @GAMPUB He doesn't want to assume someone's gender.

Comment: Then saying gender in the first place would be a strange strategy.

Comment: @GAMPUB Indeed, I don't feel the confusion but I've edited the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

- "Personne" est toujours féminin, qu'on parle d'une femme ou d'un homme.

-- J'ai soigné ce monsieur. Cette personne était devenue toute fiévreuse.

-- J'ai soigné cette dame. Cette personne était devenue toute fiévreuse.

Donc:

Que ce soit un homme ou une femme, étant donné qu'une personne s'accorde au féminin:

> Il y a une personne qui dort/endormie dans la salle, alors je ne veux pas 
>   **la** déranger.
>   --Oui, je connais ce monsieur, il s'appelle Isidore.

- On ne dirait pas une personne "*dormante dans la salle*", mais "*une personne qui dort"*.

Dormant est un participe présent, qu'on va surtout utiliser, avec la construction "en + participe présent".

-- J'ai glissé de ma chaise *en dormant*.

Il existe aussi l'adjectif "dormant", "dormante", mais ce sera utilisé principalement dans l'expression "*eaux dormantes*", cela désigne une force en sommeil, ou quelque chose qui est à l'arrêt, mais qui pourrait potentiellement reprendre vie.

-- Les *eaux dormantes* de cette rivière m'ont toujours inquiété.

Donc, qualifier une personne de "dormante" est assez étrange. Le mot approprié n'est pas "*dormant*", mais "*endormie*".

Comment: L'essentiel de la réponse ne concerne pas la question mais un commentaire sur la formulation (la réponse semble commencer après *Donc:*, pourquoi ne pas demander à l'auteur de corriger son texte dans un commentaire de la question ?

Comment: La question porte explicitement sur l'accord du pronom clitique, pas sur la maladresse concernant *dormante*.... La réponse semble plutôt commencer vers : Personne est toujours féminin...

Comment: D'où ma suggestion de répondre la question dans la réponse et de commenter la question pour les problèmes de formulation. Désolé du dérangement.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Il y a une question principale, et une erreur annexe. Ici, les 3/4 de la réponse concernent l'annexe, et 2 lignes concernent la question posée, on est donc un peu perdu en lisant le début de réponse... Peut-être, pour être plus lisible, tu pourrait marquer la séparation entre les 2 parties de ta réponse: commencer par la question posée, un trait horizontal, et un "N.B:" sur l'utilisation de "dormante" ?

Comment: Oui, je vais éditer ma réponse, entre temps la question a été éditée, ce qui est à mon avis dommage.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE C'est quelque chose que tu fais souvent, c'est pas comme ça qu'on écrit les réponses ici. C'est lourd à lire, et il y a beaucoup d'informations qui ne sont pas pertinentes. Et puis "*-- exemple*" n'est pas une bonne façon d'écrire, on a plein d'outils de formatage, autant les utiliser...