# Gerund or relative pronoun

Tags: verbes, pronoms-relatifs

"There is someone sleeping/eating/talking in the room."

A direct translation would be

> Il y a quelqu'un dormant/mangeant/parlant dans la salle.

But it was pointed out [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23417/gender-for-referring-to-une-personne) that it is better to use the relative pronoun *qui*.

> Il y a quelqu'un qui dort/mange/parle dans la salle.

Why is this?

Comment: Note that the main problem on the other topic was that you used *"dormante"* (before editing), not *"dormant"*. *Dormant* would have been totally correct even if *qui dort* sounds more natural.

Comment: In this context, it does not seem natural (see Teleporting Goat's answer) but this variation would be completely natural: *Quelqu'un dormant dans la salle, je n'ai pas voulu le réveiller.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically it's correct, but it doesn't feel natural.

I found two cases where gerunds are used. Beside those, we'll most likely use something else.

One is for talking about **two actions at once**, using *en*. For casual conversation it's pretty much the only time we use gerunds.

> Il écoute de la musique **en travaillant**

The second one is a little more literary. It makes sense to use a gerund when you're **qualifying the action** :

> Elle jetta un regard à son grand-père dormant **paisiblement** dans son fauteuil

(You don't *have* to, but if the verb is alone you'll see "*qui [verb]* " more.)

These are the most common uses, I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Là où l'anglais utilise la forme "ing", après un pronom indéfini, le français n'utilisera pas le participe présent, mais il utilisera le pronom relatif "qui" pour introduire une phrase subordonnée (proposition)

Je ne pense qu'il ait de raisons particulières, c'est une préférence que l'usage a suivi. Je pourrais retourner la question et demander: pourquoi l'anglais utilise "ing" là où le français utilise le pronom relatif.

Le participe présent n'est pas très fréquent en français: l'usage du participe présent en français se retrouve presqu'exclusivement dans la construction "en" + participe présent.
Lorsqu'une action se déroule pendant une autre action:

> *Il parle en dormant*.

Les autres utilisations, sans le "en", sont en général beaucoup plus littéraires.

> *Il va par les routes, rêvant.*
>   *Ce bel oiseau, je l'ai vu volant.*

Entre parenthèse, pour dormant: J'ai fait une petite explication ici, sur son usage un peu particulier:
[Gender for referring to "une personne"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23417/gender-for-referring-to-une-personne/23631#23631)