# Ending for gerunds

Tags: verbes, adjectifs

> Elle va par les routes, rêvant.
>
> Ces beaux oiseaux, je les ai vus volant.

In these examples of using a gerund (modified from [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23664/gerund-or-relative-pronoun)), is it necessary to change the gerund ending to match the noun, since the gerund functions like an adjective? In other words, should we use **rêvante** and **volants**?

Comment: Je reconnais ma patte. N'est-ce pas que je suis poète? ;-)

Comment: Elle va par les routes, rêvant... est moins commun et plus littéraire que: Elle va par les routes, rêvant à ses amours, qui est d'un registre de langue beaucoup plus commun.

Comment: The title is a bit misleading as it is. There is only one final mark for all French gerunds, invariable *-ant*. The question is more about the confusion between deverbal adjectives and homophonous present participles than ending for gerunds.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE And for all you know, it is still grammatical...

Comment: L'utilisateur se pose aussi la question de savoir si les phrases sont correctes ou non. Un titre n'est qu'un titre. Il faut arrêter d'être fermé sur une seule question, si la personne se pose plusieurs questions, autant l'aider au maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In French, gerunds are considered to be **en VERB-ant** while **VERB-ant** is called present participle.

The two sentences you discuss here are marginal examples but these alternatives would be natural:

- Elle va par les routes, rêvant à ses amours.
- Ces beaux oiseaux, je les ai vus, volant dans le ciel bleu.

Gerunds and present participles can be negated with *ne* contrary to the deverbal adjective:

- Elle va par les routes, ne rêvant à rien.
- Ces beaux oiseaux, je les ai vus, ne volant jamais ensemble.

Both gerunds and present participle are invariable verbal forms [different](http://grammaire.reverso.net/4_1_12_accord_des_formes_en_ant.shtml) from the deverbal adjectives rêvant/volant. Some French verbs display an [orthographic contrast](http://grammaire.reverso.net/5_6_04_orthographe_des_adjectifs_verbaux.shtml) between the two:

- CONVAINCRE convainquant (PRS_PART), convaincant (ADJ)
- FATIGUER fatiguant (PRS_PART), fatigant (ADJ)

Answer (score 1):

Beaucoup d'accords sont homophones (indistinguables à l'oral). Mais l'oreille d'un locuteur expérimenté (natif ou non) connaît bien les règles, il suffit de trouver des cas ou l'accord n'est pas homophone:

- Ces oies, je les ai vues <s>volantes très haut</s>
- Ces oies, je les ai vues volant très haut.

La première phrase sonne incorrecte, pas la seconde, donc on ne fait pas l'accord.

PS: il y a en plus ici une ambiguïté sur "volant" qui peut être un adjectif (signifiant "en état de voler"), et dans ce cas on fait naturellement l'accord: "Ces "Alouette", je les ai vu volantes" dit juste que vous vous  souvenez avoir vu ces hélicoptères quand ils étaient en service actif. Le faut de rajouter "très haut" dans les exemples élimine cette ambiguïté.

Comment: Désolé, mais je ne comprends pas vraiment cette réponse. Tu veux dire qu’il est évident que ces deux phrases sont fausses ?

Comment: Beaucoup d'accords sont homophones (indistinguables à l'oral). Mais l'oreille d'un locuteur expérimenté (natif ou non) connaît bien les règles, il suffit de trouver des cas ou l'accord n'est pas homophone, comme dans l'exemple que je donne. La première phrase sonne incorrecte, pas la seconde, donc on ne fait pas l'accord.

Comment: J'ai édité pour plus de clarté, c'est vrai qu'il faudrait éviter de présenter une phrase incorrecte et une phrase correcte de la même façon.

Comment: Et on ne doit pas faire l'accord avec le verbe (*vu*) ?

Comment: Pas d'accord avec ce qui est dit, ces phrases sont bien grammaticalement correctes, et compréhensibles. Ces oies, je les ai vu volant, est une phrase poétique (pas une phrase de tous les jours), mais grammaticalement correcte. Elle revient au même que "Je les ai vu marchant". Je suis habituée à lire de la poésie, mais pour certaines personnes, les formulations poétiques hors contexte sonnent fausses. Je vous trouverai des poèmes si vous mettez en doute qu'elles soient écrites en bon français, c'est même du très bon français.

Comment: Flemme de recherche des poèmes pour l'instant, mais dans cette page, on donne l'exemple "Je l'ai vu marchant dans la rue", ce qui est exactement la même construction que mon poème avec les oies. http://www.allemandfacile.com/forum/lire.php?num=14&msg=46407&titre=Participe+pr%E9sent+fran%E7ais

Comment: @user11550 si... (corrigé)

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Je crois que vous (toi et Xenoid) confondez les participes présents et les [adjectifs verbaux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectif_verbal). "Je les ai vu volants" est un adjectif verbal, et s'accorde. "Je les ai vu volant très haut" est un participe présent, invariable. Les adjectifs verbaux sont assez rares (comme tu dis, poétiques, mais correct) et ne sont pas bien connus. Moi-même j'ai appris récemment la différence avec le participe présent. Par exemple on dit "*Je les ai trouvées tremblant**es**, affamé**es** et frigorifié**es**.*".

Comment: Je n'écrirait pas "Je les ai vu volants". ça m'apparaît (personnellement) comme une faute. Je n'ai pas du tout l'impression que ça soit objet d'un accord.

Comment: @perce-neige ... parce que dans ton vocabulaire "volant" n'est pas un adjectif. Mais dans le vocabulaire aéronautique, il peut l'être.

Comment: Je n'ai marqué nulle part que volant est un adjectif, d'ailleurs il ne s'accorde pas, le mot peut être remplacé par un autre ...ant en gardant la même structure de phrase.

Comment: @perce-neige Et bien tu peux remarquer [ici](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/volant#Adjectif) :) Et il manque le sens "aéronautique" du terme (qui signifie "en état de voler")

Comment: Pas vu "aéronautique" dans la page. Ce n'est pas tout à fait la même chose ici, entre les dragons-volants ou les poissons qui ont intrinsèquement la faculté de voler, qui s'est longtemps écrit avec un tiret, et une personne, rêvant, marchant, volant, peu importe. En état de voler = qualité intrinsèque.

Answer (score 0):

Dans ces vers, "révant" et "volant" sont 2 participes présents, que l'on peut remplacer par "elle qui révait" et "qui volaient".

Comment: Tu veux dire qu'on peut dire "Elle va par les routes, elle qui révait" et "Ces beaux oiseaux, je les ai vus qui volaient" ?

Comment: @user11550 Je pense que oui, mais c'est des formulations tellement rares (les 4 phrases, les originales et celles que tu viens de donner) que je ne peux pas confirmer à 100% (Quand je dis rare, je veux dire rare même dans la littérature).

Comment: @user11550 D'ailleurs "*elle qui rêvait*" donne l'impression que c'est  quelque chose qu'elle fait tout le temps, pas spécialement en ce moment. Comme dans : "*Thor, lui qui fait tomber la foudre*".

Comment: En rêvant, est un meilleur équivalent que "elle qui rêvait", car ll peut y avoir certaines subtilités de sens, avec "en + ... ant", tu as l'équivalent, sauf que c'est beaucoup moins littéraire/poétique. Pas si rare en poésie.

Answer (score 0):

Tu confonds adjectif (qui s'accorde tout le temps), et participe présent (gérondif: qui ne s'accorde jamais).

*Je vais rêvant, par les chemins* = *Je marche en rêvant, par les chemins.*

Ces deux formules reviennent au même, grammaticalement, et pour le sens, sauf que  la première est beaucoup plus poétique.

Tu n'accorderais pas "en rêvant", donc "rêvant" ne s'accorde pas plus.

Ce n'est pas la même chose qu'un adjectif en "ant" qui ressemble parfois à un participe présent. Rêvant n'est clairement pas un adjectif.

http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3715

Souviens-toi, j'avais formulé ces phrases poétiques, pour montrer les rares emplois du participe présent, non précédé de "en".

Comment: [RÊVANT](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/revant#art74385) n'est pas un adjectif dans le contexte discuté ici...

Comment: C'est justement ce que ma réponse dit. Je dis qu'il s'agit d'un participe présent, donc il ne s'accord pas.Je n'ai pas été claire? Je veux bien clarifier, mais où? Je ne vois pas où j'ai dit que c'était un adjectif? Où est l’ambiguïté?